# View component in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, widget, cells, apotomo

Is there any gem available for implementing view components in Rails? I had look at 'cells' and 'apotomo'. I found them good but documentation is not updated for the latest versions. Any one knows about any other good gem for implementing widgets kind of structures in rails?

Comment: Thank you @Tachyons. What about using AngularJS with rails.

Comment: I opted for AngularJS with rails approach. Till now it worked pretty well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [React js](https://facebook.github.io/react/) for view level components , use [react-rails](http://react-rails) to integrate it with rails

Answer (score 0):

If you are concerned with performance, you should try solutions like [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/) , [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), [React.js](https://facebook.github.io/react/), [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/) or any front end MVC framework.

Your code can be organized and run faster than use Apomoto or Rails partials, for example.